IPA Pronunciation - what is the difference between ð, θ, and θj
In what dialects are ð, θ, and θj pronounced differently? My own dialect is a mix of Northern Californian and Midwestern, and I couldn't identify any speech pattern off the top of my head where these would be different other than the slightest distinction in the length with which they are held.
For reference:
ð   thy, father

θ   thigh, path

θj  enthuse

I'm in NYC, and /ð/ is the voiced th of father or then, while /θ/ is the voiceless th of think or thin. I'm not aware of any words in which I hear /θj/ as distinct from /θ/.

What makes any difference are the vowel sounds that follow...so you say enth-use for enthooz?

So you're saying you hear no difference between "thy thigh" and "thigh thigh" other than length? And "Arthur" (with θ) and "farther" (with ð) rhyme?

Cambridge gives US pronunciation of enthuse as /ɪnˈθjuːz/ but the audio recording is more like /ɪnˈθuːz/. I'd guess the latter is standard US English but maybe both are possible.

In my British accent, I would pronounce nth(-degree) as /ɛnθ/ and (the verb) use as /juːz/, so enthuse as /ɛnθjuːz/ is hardly a stretch.

Can you hear the difference between the "th" sounds in author and bother? Also: do you have recordings of yourself saying those words?

/ɛnθjuːz/ or /ɪnˈθjuːz/ is definitely the UK English, to match "use". But the OP speaks American English, so I assume that's what the question is about.

The /θj/ of enthuse is a simple θ; the j attaches to the u in /ɛnθjuːz/

The key difference between ð and θ is that between voiced and unvoiced sounds respectively. Voiced involve vocal cords. See https://britishaccentcourse.com/lessons/back-to-basics-voicing-consonants/
